# Chinese character are in different sizes in some apps (Eclipse, Notepad++, MSSQL)

Tags: windows, eclipse, character, notepad++, chinese-locale

I'm using Windows 10 pro and for some reason when I'm having Chinese character in any coding related program which not allows setting directly a Chinese font, most of the characters shown in a normal way and some in a different and smaller font, everything I tried, including changing font, change encoding, adding Chinese language pack to windows or changing windows to Chinese did not work, can someone try help me to fix it? Thanks!

Characters in Notepad++:

[image: characters in notepad++]

Characters in Eclipse:

[image: characters in eclipse]

Comment: What font is it? Can you try Microsoft YaHei?

Comment: Please add some Chinese sample characters to your question. What do you mean exactly by _different sizes_? Not monospace, different from each other, different from ASCII characters, ...?

Comment: @ice1000 - I installed this font, but it does not show this font as an option in eclipse or the other apps when I'm trying to change font, it shows only Latin fonts.

Comment: @howlger - As you can see those character are in normal size and font in the screenshot:
诊号，病人费别
and those are smaller and in a different font:
门，别

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blurriness of the two too small characters `门` and `别` indicates that they are missing in the chosen font and have been replaced by characters of a bitmap/raster font.

Make sure to have a font installed and chosen that contains all the characters you want to use:

- [`门` (U+95E8) font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/95e8/fontsupport.htm)
- [`别` (U+522B) font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/522b/fontsupport.htm)

For example, the font [BabelStone Han (download link at the bottom of the page)](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html) supports these characters.

In Eclipse, the text editor font can be changed in *Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts: Basic > Text Font*.